# Remove jetty server from Jhipster 3.9.0

Tags: tomcat, jhipster

I have upgraded the jhipster framework to latest version which is 3.9.0 and I can see the jetty server is running along which is not required. How do I remove the jetty server and run with embedded tomcat as usual? Also, it gives lots of unnecessary logs hiding or making it difficult to see the application logs. Pls suggest.

Comment: This is rather strange because JHipster has never used Jetty. In the past, it used Tomcat but few years ago it switched to Undertow. Are you sure it's Jetty and not Netty (which is used for Reactive programming)? Which version of jhipster-framework are you upgrading from? Have you diff'ed the output of `mvnw dependency:tree`?

Comment: Its not upgraded. i just started using new jhipster version by creating the microservice application using jhipster. And yes, Jetty is running around and its really very hard to see my application logs

Comment: Its the eclipse jetty. Apologies.  Jetty is running from spark api.